# WebdriverIO Allure report does not work with issues tag

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

According to the Webdriverio docs at https://webdriver.io/docs/allure-reporter/ the allure reporter should recognise @addIssue(value) - I have added this to a test and generated a report and no issue is shown.

While looking at the docs, it says to add a severity, we need to use `@addSeverity(value)` however, I have found that `@severity=value`

With this in mind, I have tried using `@issue(value)` and still nothing.

To complicate matters, I am adding the tag inside a cucumber feature file.

So the question is does anyone know how to add these?

( I have configured TMS and Issues in the config file.)

Answer (score 1):

I was being a bit silly here.
if `@severity=critical` works, then to add a link it needs to be `@issue=1234` or `@addTestId=1234` - no brackets are needed